# Authentication by JWT and Authorization by local database

Tags: spring-security, oauth, jwt, authorization, auth0

In my Spring Boot application, my users are authenticated by a third party and I receive a Jwt which I parse using a NimbusJwtDecoder in Spring Security.

```
 @Override
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/api/private").authenticated()
            .mvcMatchers("/api/organisations").authenticated()
            .mvcMatchers("/api/project").authenticated()
            .mvcMatchers("/api/user").authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
```

This works fine, now I want to add authorization by retrieving the roles and permissions which I would store on my own database.  I have the username from the Jwt, but I am lost how to plug it all in.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you authenticate the user with JWT, add the username to the principal of the SecurityContext.

Create an AuthorisationFilter class that implements the javax.servelet.Filter interface.  In this class get the userdetails from the database using the username from the securityContextHolder, and add the grantedAuthorities to the context.

In the SecurityConfig create a FilterRegistrationBean which sets the filter as the AuthorisationFilter, urlPatterns as ("/*") or as appropriate, and the Order as Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE